# Are you completely sure anything you have done [is/has been] of your own free will?

Tags: tense, tense-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

> Are you completely sure anything you have done **is** of your own free
>   will?
>
> Are you completely sure anything you have done **has been** of your own
>   free will?

Might I trouble you to tell me whether both of them is grammatical or not?

Comment: I think the second one is better although some people may argue that the first one can be correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first reaction is that both are grammatical, but the first is *semantically* wrong. Something that has been done is no longer extant, so the present tense can't be applied.

The second is valid in all senses, but so is

> Are you completely sure anything you have done **was** of your own free will?

Comment: Thank you so much. If it is 'something that someone has been doing', Is it still be extant? - In this case, can the present tense be applied?  "Are you completely sure anything you have been doing is of your own free will"?

Comment: Yes, that works.